# While loop and increment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, increment

In the following function I need to increment the `years` variable in order to find the amount of years that need to pass before I reach a desired profit. I noticed that this function does not work if I use `years++` instead of `++years`. I understand the difference between the two methods of increment, however, I still do not understand while in this particular case `years++` causes the loop to be executed only once.

```js
 function calculateYears(investment, interestRate, tax, desiredProfit) {
        var years = 0;
        while(investment < desiredProfit && ++years){
          investment += (investment * interestRate) * (1 - tax);
        }
    
        return years;
    }
    var years = calculateYears(1000, 0.05, 0.18, 1100);
    console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I still do not understand while in this particular case years++ causes
>   the loop to be executed only once.

because `&& years++` translates to `&& 0` which will translates to **falsey value**.

If you want to use `years++`, initialize `years` to `1`

```js
function calculateYears(investment, interestRate, tax, desiredProfit) {
    var years = 1;
    while(investment < desiredProfit && years++){
      investment += (investment * interestRate) * (1 - tax);
    }

    return years - 1;
}
console.log(calculateYears(1000, 0.05, 0.18, 1100));
```

Comment: It returns 4 instead of 3. See my answer

Comment: @MaxMaximilian Thanks for pointing out, there will be an extra increment while checking for final `while`, I have made the updates.

Comment: @gurvinder372 your explanation is very clear and useful. Thank you! I made a test when changing var years = 1. It gave interesting result - while loop works, which is perfect. But it does not give the logic needed - as the value of investment in the first loop need to be taken as the one before the first year passed. In conclusion, for the function to give proper result I need to initialize it with 0. But having your explanation, as well as answers from others, I can understand now why the things work the way they work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can see now that Max has pointed it out as well. But I mark your answer as solution to my question, because my point was why the while loop did not execute with that specific configuration, rather than how to change it to make it work. But @MaxMaximilian thanks a lot too!

Comment: @bakrall Glad it worked for you. Your problem was less to do with `while` and more with how **logical operators** work. `&&` will evaluate second condition regardless of whether first one has succeeded or not.

Comment: I think, that way isn't very clean. That works, which is good, but 1) it makes unnecessary calculations after the loop, 2) on each loop it checks `&& years++` which makes unnecessary calcs too. As programmers we should make code cleaner, because that can show up in bigger projects where you need to create something which does perform better in speed etc. But yeah, that explains the root of the issue, so good answer gurvinder372

Comment: @MaxMaximilian I agree that this isn't the cleanest and there can be more readable ways of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

It gets executed only once because the value of `years` used for checking truthiness is `0`, i.e. before incrementing.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

Answer (score 2):

You should use `years++` inside the loop:

```
function calculateYears(investment, interestRate, tax, desiredProfit) {
    var years = 0;
    while(investment < desiredProfit){
      investment += (investment * interestRate) * (1 - tax);
      years++;
    }

    return years;
}
alert(calculateYears(1000, 0.05, 0.18, 1100));
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/f35nzvxr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
while(investment < desiredProfit && ++years)
```

this condition will not execute because as years is 0 and it increment after the 1 loop so it is like

```
desiredProfit && 0 -> false/0
```

and after

```
investment < 0 //is always false
```

Answer (score 0):

You did forget that your while loop is not incrementing the value of years

```
 while(investment < desiredProfit && ++years){
  investment += (investment * interestRate) * (1 - tax); years++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this

```
let i = -6;
let end = 9;
while ((i++ || true) && i < end) {
...do something...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `&& years++` translates to `&& 0` which will translates to false value.

If you want to use `years++`, initialize years to 1.